# Deny access to the ec2 by tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-iam

I want to deny access to the ec2 that has a "Type" tag with "MyInstance" value.

I have Josh user with EC2FullAccess assigned policy.
I have created policy with such a rule:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/Type": "MyInstance"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

And assigned this policy to Josh user. But Josh still have access to the instances with Type:MyInstance tag.

Also, I have tried to Deny describe instances:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "ec2:*",
      "Resource": "*",
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": "ec2:Describe*",
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "ec2:ResourceTag/Type": "MyInstance"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But, without success. Can you please help me with such a restriction? Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "deny access"? What, specifically, do you wish to deny them from doing?

Comment: I want that Josh user doesn't see ec2 instances with "Type:MyInstance" tag in the list of instances, using aws console.
Or at least, Josh user shouldn't see details(public ip, instance id, etc.) of such instances.

Answer (score 2):

What you request is not possible.

The `DescribeInstances()` call is either permitted or denied. If permitted, information about *all instances* is returned.

The [Actions, Resources, and Condition Keys for Amazon EC2 - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/list_amazonec2.html) page does not show any **conditions** for the API call, so it would not be possible to craft a policy that only permits requests with certain filters/Instance IDs specified.

The `ec2:ResourceTag` condition can only be used on API calls that are shown on that page with `ec2:ResourceTag` mentioned in the **Conditions** column.

If you wish to segregate information in that manner, then you will either need to use separate AWS Accounts, or you will need to create an "information layer" that can apply detailed rules and make information API calls on behalf of your users, only relaying back permitted information.